# ABP Framework Fluent Validation

Tags: fluentvalidation, abp

How can I put my custom fluent validation interceptor into the method invoacation's pipeline so I can handle the returned validation error by myslef like returning a global API response for all of my project's API.
So I want to:

1. Disable the ABP validation handling which is throwing the AbpValidationException.
2. Inject my own handler.